# LoadError when executing compiled Rails Warbler JAR file

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

When I warble my project with the compiled command I get the following error when running it (`java -jar mywar.war -S rails s`):

`ERROR: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) use 'java_import' to load normal Java classes: config.boot`

I'm using the 2.x warbler, and it works fine if I warble without the compiled flag. I need to use 2.x because I need JRuby9000 support.

It's worth noting that I also have found I need to unzip the war file, copy my config.ru from my project into the WEB-INF directory and then rezip it to have it work (otherwise I receive and error about its absence). It's possible whatever I'm doing wrong to cause me to require to copy config.ru into the jar manually may also be causing my issues with the `compiled` flag.

I have noticed I have to do the config.ru copy paste even with stable versions of warbler and earlier JRuby versions.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a bug to report ... I'm not 100% sure but *config.ru* should not be compiled as JRuby-Rack assumes a *config.ru* file (won't check for .class like ordinary `load 'application'` calls do), thus it sounds like it's simply not copied over.

Comment: try to provide a simple Rack app and full traces for reproduction with the report